# Is there a way to repeat code in a simple way?

Tags: python

I am making a python quiz and everything is going well but there are some things that aren't working. Such as when the user has answered all the questions, I want the code to ask the user if they would like to play the quiz again. I have done the part where the code asks the user if they would like to play again but I don't know how to repeat the quiz. I have tried things such as making the quiz a variable and printing the variable but that didn't work. Please help me.

Here's the code, the part where I ask if the user wants to play again is at the bottom.

```
import random
import time

Question_list =  {
   "How many years are there in a millennium?":"1000",
   "How many days are there in 2 years?":"730", 
   "How many years are there in a half a century?":"50"
   } 

question = list (Question_list.keys())
#input answer here 
while True:
    if not question:
        break
    ques = random.choice(question)
    print(ques)
    while True:
        answer = input('Your Answer: ' )
        # if correct, moves onto next question
        if answer.lower() == Question_list[ques]:
            print("Correct Answer")
            break
        else:
            #if wrong, Asks the same question again
            print("Wrong Answer. Try again") 
    question.remove(ques)

play_again = input("Would you like to play the quiz again\n")

if play_again == "yes":
  print()
  # i want it to repeat the quiz but don't know how to do that.

# this part works fine
else:
  print("Thanks for playing")
  time.sleep(2)
  exit()
```

Comment: To repeat some code you need a while loop, which you seem to be comfortable with already.

Comment: One simple way to solve this is to put everything inside a `while True:`

Comment: Move the part you would like to repeat to a function and call it based on the condition

Comment: @HarshSaini doing that will break it because of `question.remove(ques)` A new `while True:` needs to be added around everything or creating a function of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an infinite loop for asking multiple questions. You can also put an infinite loop to play multiple quizes like this:

```
import random
import time

Question_list =  {
   "How many years are there in a millennium?":"1000",
   "How many days are there in 2 years?":"730", 
   "How many years are there in a half a century?":"50"
   } 

while True:
    question = list (Question_list.keys())
    #input answer here 
    while True:
        if not question:
            break
        ques = random.choice(question)
        print(ques)
        while True:
            answer = input('Your Answer: ' )
            # if correct, moves onto next question
            if answer.lower() == Question_list[ques]:
                print("Correct Answer")
                break
            else:
                #if wrong, Asks the same question again
                print("Wrong Answer. Try again") 
        question.remove(ques)

    play_again = input("Would you like to play the quiz again\n")

    #if answer is not yes, break the outer infinite loop
    if play_again != "yes": 
      print("Thanks for playing")
      break 
      time.sleep(2)
      exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, use the `while True` outside, then it could always run if `play_again` is `yes` and add break in the bottom if want to stop.

```
import random
import time
while True:
    Question_list =  {
           "How many years are there in a millennium?":"1000",
           "How many days are there in 2 years?":"730", 
           "How many years are there in a half a century?":"50"
           } 

    question = list (Question_list.keys())
    #input answer here 
    while True:
        if not question:
            break
        ques = random.choice(question)
        print(ques)
        while True:
            answer = input('Your Answer: ' )
            # if correct, moves onto next question
            if answer.lower() == Question_list[ques]:
                print("Correct Answer")
                break
            else:
                #if wrong, Asks the same question again
                print("Wrong Answer. Try again") 
        question.remove(ques)

    play_again = input("Would you like to play the quiz again\n")

    if play_again == "yes":
        print()
        # i want it to repeat the quiz but don't know how to do that.
    else:
        break
# this part works fine

print("Thanks for playing")
time.sleep(2)
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a while loop which repeats the question until a certain condition is met. Use a variable which is true and while it is true the game continues, but once a condition is met which should end the game, switch the variable to false and the while loop should stop.